# Python как отнять импортированный файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Есть **`2`** файла: **test.py** и **test1.py**

**test.py**:

```
from test1 import * 

n = n - 1
print(n)
```

**test1.py**:

```
def mp():
    n=5

mp()
```

В **test.py** выдаёт ошибку:

> name 'n' is not defined.

Как исправить? Это как пример.

Answer (score 1):

```
def mp():
    global n
    n = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

**text.py**

```
from text1_1292899 import mp     # + mp


#n=n-1

print(mp() - 1)                  # +++
```

**text1.py**

```
def mp():
    n = 5
    return n         # +++ 

mp()
```

Comment: Да, это сработает. А вот если там будет n и v которые тоже нужно отнять?) То что делать?))

Comment: @GusionDark если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, приложите пример.